# Singleform with different database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to make a form in php where there will be two categories. One for the Student profile details and another for the student's
marks details. Now the main problem is all this will be in one single form means in one page and the categories like student details will be save in student detail table of the database and the marks will be save in another database called  marks database. I also need CRUD for these two categories.So how to do that?

Any suggestion and help will be highly appreciable.

Comment: I think you may have the concepts `database` and `table` mixed up. You likely want to store the data in two seperate tables of the same database. Furthermore this question is overly broad. What specific part(s) are you having trouble with? (Please edit the question with specific details, until then: voting to close this question).

Answer (score 0):

Well there is no direct link between a form and a database table, so what is your problem?

Why don't you do the mysql_query() on each table one after another when you handle the form post?

Comment: Actually I want  that when I will click on save button it will save the input fields in two databases according to their category.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your form like this in order to separate the tables:

```
<input type="text" name="data[student][name]" />
<input type="text" name="data[category][name]" />
```

you PHP script then goes through the data and save it in the corresponding tables:

```
foreach($_POST['data'] as $table=>$row){
    // do your insert statemnet here (don't foregt to escape the Parameters!)
}
```